# Text goes out of div (CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have title with text on mobile

Here is code

```css
.ui-bar-b, .ui-page-theme-b .ui-bar-inherit, html .ui-bar-b .ui-bar-inherit, html .ui-body-b .ui-bar-inherit, html body .ui-group-theme-b .ui-bar-inherit {
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
    border-color: #1b1b1b;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.ui-header, .ui-footer {
    border-width: 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
}

#step_4_0 .ui-title, .payment-page .ui-title {
    overflow: visible;
    margin: 0 15%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title {
    font-size: 1em;
    min-height: 1.1em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 30%;
    padding: .7em 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    outline: 0!important;
}
.ui-header .ui-title {
    margin: 0 15% !important;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="noflow ui-header ui-bar-b" role="banner">
      <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Betal senest kl 23.30 i dagfffdfskjdbfksdbfksdjbdfksdbfkjsdbjfksjbdfkjbsdfkjbsdkfjbsdkjfbsdkjfbksdbfkjsdbf</h1>
  </div>
```

On snippet all ok and line breaks

But on mobile it goes out of div

And Here is screen of how it looks

[image]

I cant't understood, why line break not works and how to fix this on mobile?

Thank's for help so much.

Comment: If you see my question's code, you can see, that I already tried @divy3993

Comment: You've set `white-space: nowrap;` which tells the browser *not* to wrap the line, so there will not be any line break.

Comment: Remove this : `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Thank's it helps! @Terry

Comment: @Balance you must have a media query that is removing your ellipsis if that is what you see on mobile as your snippet works for all screen sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you have set `white-space: nowrap`, which tells the browser to never wrap/break the overflow into a new line. Removing that line will fix your issue.

Comment: ...but might create new issues. It's done so that text gets clipped (overflow:ellipsis), depending on the size. Removing white-space:nowrap will break that behaviour :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem will solve with just white-space:wrap/normal. Because there is no break in your last word. So to be on safer side you can also use below property along with white-space for mobile

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove white-space: nowrap or simply try this if that doesn't work:

```
white-space: normal; //instead of white-space nowrap in your css class .ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title {
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply remove `white-space: nowrap;` from your code as others said in the comments and voila.

```css
.ui-bar-b,
.ui-page-theme-b .ui-bar-inherit,
html .ui-bar-b .ui-bar-inherit,
html .ui-body-b .ui-bar-inherit,
html body .ui-group-theme-b .ui-bar-inherit {
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  border-color: #1b1b1b;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.ui-header,
.ui-footer {
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  position: relative;
}

#step_4_0 .ui-title,
.payment-page .ui-title {
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0 15%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 500px;
}

.ui-header .ui-title,
.ui-footer .ui-title {
  font-size: 1em;
  min-height: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 30%;
  padding: .7em 0;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0 !important;
}

.ui-header .ui-title {
  margin: 0 15% !important;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="noflow ui-header ui-bar-b" role="banner">
  <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Betal senest kl 23.30 i dagfffdfskjdbfksdbfksdjbdfksdbfkjsdbjfksjbdfkjbsdfkjbsdkfjbsdkjfbsdkjfbksdbfkjsdbf</h1>
</div>
```